# How to make the formula unique to ignore a column

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have this formula in a google spreadsheet cell which finds unique rows in the columns A:F.

It works fine but I need to the formula to ignore the content of the column C. I mean that the formula should take two rows as equals even if the value in cell 'C' is different.

Is there a way to do this?

```
=unique(A:F)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can either use:

```
=UNIQUE({A:B, D:F})
```

[image: 0]

or like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({UNIQUE({A:B, D:F}), 
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(UNIQUE({A:B, D:F}),,1), A:C, 3, 0))}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col6,Col3,Col4,Col5", 0))
```

[image: 0]

or try perhaps:

```
=SORTN(A1:F3, 10, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0)
```

[image: 0]